# Algolia + Woocommerce hierarchical indexing of categories

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, algolia

I've done multiple Algolia installations. Now, I am finishing another one on Wordpress, indexing Woocommerce products. Using Algolia Woocommerce WP plugin (https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress)

Everything looks good so far, although there is a small issue with indexing product categories:

In Wordpress they are hierarchical, but when they get indexed they are flat

```
categories: ['parent', 'child', 'child']
```

My question is: is there any way I could make the indexing "smarter" and the output like:

```
categories : {
    parent: ['child', 'child2'],
    parent2: ['child3', 'child4', 'child5']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write some custom code in the indexer https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-wordpress/blob/c2b791d3a018f2b3c4e7fe46815bc412ccce90f6/core/Indexer.php that will turn categories into that schema

```
{
  "objectID": "123",
  "categories": {
    "lvl0": "child",
    "lvl1": "child > child2"
  }
}
```

Then you could easily leverage it either using:

- the JS Helper https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#hierarchical-facets
- InstantSearch.js https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/